# Do other creatures have to survive to deal damage back to Alpha Brawl's target?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When [Alpha Brawl](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=262657) is played, after the target creature deals damage to the opponents creatures, do only the ones that survive do damage back?

Answer (score 8):

**Creatures dealt lethal damage will still deal their damage back to Alpha Brawl's target.**

From the Oracle rulings, which you can see on [the card's Gatherer page](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=262657):

> 1/22/2011   The two parts of Alpha Brawl's effect happen sequentially: first the targeted creature deals damage, then the other creatures deal damage. State-based actions aren't checked in the middle, so creatures that are dealt lethal damage by the targeted creature will still deal damage.

Why does it work the way it does? Because, in Magic, you carry out the instructions on a card sequentially, but you also do all the actions as one event, and only check for state-based actions and triggers afterward. "This creature took so much damage that it's going to the graveyard now" is a state-based action.

Note also that all creatures killed by Alpha Brawl will go to the graveyard at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

The ruling is right there on gatherer:

> The two parts of Alpha Brawl's effect happen sequentially: first the
>   targeted creature deals damage, then the other creatures deal damage.
>   State-based actions aren't checked in the middle, so creatures that
>   are dealt lethal damage by the targeted creature will still deal
>   damage.

All the opponent's creatures will deal damage back, regardless of whether or not they die.